# Accessing routes file from root folder

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a Play project called `ScalaWeb`. Its routes file is in the file `ScalaWeb/conf/routes`.

Within `ScalaWeb` I have a subproject called `server` which has the main controller in the file `ScalaWeb/server/app/controllers/Application.scala`.

From here, I am trying to call the routes file like this:

```
Redirect(controllers.routes.Application.getPage(Id))
```

However, on this line I get this error:

> object routes is not a member of package controllers in server/app/controllers/Application.scala:35

Comment: try `routes.Application.getPage(Id)`

Comment: I tried that as well. I get the same error.